# Pass list parameter to SQL expression

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute

I am trying to pass the results of a list as a parameter in a SelectLayerByAttribute expression to output and excel spreadsheet of the attribute table. Here is the code, the results create an empty excel spreadsheet.  I am little lost.

```python
# Make feature layer
   arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(OwnerList, "OwnerTable")
   with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("OwnerTable", "ClubName") as cursor:
        myList = sorted({str(row[0]) for row in cursor})

        # Create Club lists
        for i in myList:
            expression = '"ClubName" = \'str(i)\' '
            arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("OwnerTable", "NEW_SELECTION", expression)
            arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion("OwnerTable", out_xls + "_" + i + ".xls")
```

Solution:
 # Make feature layer
   arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(OwnerList, "OwnerTable")
   with arcpy.da.SearchCursor("OwnerTable", "ClubName") as cursor:
        myList = sorted({str(row[0]) for row in cursor})
        print myList

```
    # Create Club lists
    for i in myList:
        expression = ' "ClubName" = \'%s\' ' % i
        print expression
        print arcpy.AddMessage(expression)
        arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("OwnerTable", "NEW_SELECTION", expression )
        arcpy.TableToExcel_conversion("OwnerTable", out_xls + "_" + i + ".xls")
```

Comment: Try using arcpy.AddMessage(expression) before Select Layer by Attribute to make sure it's what you expect.

Comment: cndnflyr - the results from the AddMessage returns a value of "None" for each item in the list.

Comment: Keep moving back up the stream of code to see where the break is.  Next check myList with arcpy.AddMessage(myList.ToString()).  You might not need to designate ToString()...  I always find that somewhere I make an assumption as to what I expect is happening and what is actually happening.  It's a lot faster if you work in these checks as you write the code, and keep verifying your results as you go.  Once you have it working then all these checks can be discarded.

Comment: I had a print myList in the code that returns ['3LKS', 'BOBOEN', 'CCC', 'ESD', 'FR', 'FRC', 'HODAG', 'LAC', 'NEWTOM', 'NTU', 'NWP', 'SC', 'VC', 'WIL'] which are the correct (expected) results.  I just need to pass these into the expression one at a time. Right now I get the spreadsheets created and formatted properly just no data.

Comment: Solved the issue, here it is.   

            expression = ' "ClubName" = \'%s\' ' % i

Comment: Well done!  I'm glad you worked it out.  Write it as an answer to your own question instead of in these comments.